# Request parameter on Zend not working

Tags: zend-framework, request, this

My Url is http://local.xyz.com/category/guys-tee#?c=plain-polos

```
$request = $this->getRequest();
$cat = $this->getRequest->getParam('c');
echo $cat;
exit;
```

Not Able to get values for c....

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$cat = $this->getRequest->getParam('c');
```

change to:

```
$cat = $this->getRequest()->getParam('c');
```

Also Hash in URL is a problem. It has to be after parameters.

http://local.xyz.com/category/guys-tee?c=plain-polos#something

Also pass parameters "Zend way" so it looks better :)